# Compiling Linux for an H8/532 microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, linux

Can I compile and run Linux on an H8/532 microcontroller? From what I've read, it is possible for some of the models.

Family: [H8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H8_Family)

Specific Model: [HD6475328CP10](https://www.rocelec.com/part/RENRNSHD6475328CP10)

**Research**

- http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1506.2/05292.html
- http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet_pdf/hitachi-semiconductor/HD6475328CP10.pdf

Comment: If you have read that it is possible, what do you expect from us? We can't prove a negative. Why don't you try it?

Comment: It's possible for some models, but not all. I was hoping that someone may know more than me.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "uclinux h8/300"? The particular version of linux that appears to be viable is not full linux but "uclinux".

Comment: Cripes. I didn't know the H8 (of which I have a box of windowed parts here from 30 years ago, thereabouts) still exists! Nice instruction set and nifty method (back then) of programming them as if they were a standard eeprom memory part. But I'm shocked the parts still abound. .... Oh, I see. Rochester. Now that makes sense.